# Meaning of 'mu' in 'uWSGI' Web-server gateway interface?

Tags: uwsgi

What does 'mu' stand for in uWSGI? I see that `uWSGI pronounced "mu wiz gee"`. And WSGI means web-server gateway interface. But what about the 'mu' part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the letter [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)), `μ`, which looks like `u` if you squint. Since mu is the letter for [the SI prefix `micro-`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-), the idea is that uWSGI (or rather, μWSGI) would be a small WSGI.

However, the official documentation or repository for uWSGI don't use the letter mu, nor does the official logo, so I'd pronounce it "You Whiskey".